# How do I make my program show the reverse order of the integers that was entered by the user?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assign58{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numintegers, j; 
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
    numintegers = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Now enter " + numintegers + " integers: "); 
    int[] integers = new int[numintegers];

    for (int i=0; i < integers.length; i++){
      integers[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
      int[] reverse = new int[integers.length];

      for (i = 0, j = reverse.length - 1; i < reverse.length; i++, j--){
        reverse[j] = integers[i];
      }
    }

    System.out.print("In reverse: ");

    for (int i=0; i < integers.length; i++)
      System.out.print(integers[i] + " ");

    }
  }
```

So if the integers were `3 4 6 2 9`, how would I change the following from the code above:

```
for (int i=0; i < integers.length; i++)
    System.out.print(integers[i] + " ");
```

to make the output come out as:

```
9 - 2 - 6 - 4 - 3
```

REMEMBER I need it to come out in reverse order and I want those dashes in between those numbers and there should be no dash after the last number.

I hope someone can help me! Thanks!

Comment: for (int i=integers.length; i > 0; i--)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for printing the array in reverse order.

```
int j = integers.length;        //integers is the array in which the values are stored.

for(int k=j-1; k>=0; k--)
    System.out.print(integers[k]+"-");
```

Answer (score 0):

reverse the forloop to get the reverse order

```
for (int i=integers.length-1; i>=0 i--)
System.out.print(integers[i] + "-");
```

Comment: it will give ArrayIndexOutOfException. You need to use (i=integers.length-1)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = integers.length; i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(integers[i] + " - ");
}
System.out.print(integers[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
for (int i=0; i < integers.length; i++){
      integers[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
      int[] reverse = new int[integers.length];

      for (i = 0, j = reverse.length - 1; i < reverse.length; i++, j--){
        reverse[i] = integers[j]+" ";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print(reverse[0]);
for (int i=1; i < integers.length; i++)
    System.out.print(" - " + reverse[i]);
```

the other proposed solutions would print one `-` too much.

Answer (score 0):

Either you could traverse the Array from the end

```
for(int i = integers.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(integers[i] + " ");
}
```

or you could use a `Stack<Integer>` to push all entered numbers and pop them in the reverse order.

```
Stack<Integer> integers = new Stack<Integer>();

for (int i=0; i < numIntegers; i++){
  integers.push(keyboard.nextInt());
}

System.out.print("In reverse: ");

while(!integers.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.print(integers.pop() + " ");

}
```